# Javascript can't load files from other directories

Tags: javascript, php

My javascript code can only load the file when it's in the same directory as the code. The directory is `/includes/friend.php` it will load the file if my javascript code is in `/includes` but not anywhere else. Why is this?

I have tried `../includes/friend.php` but it does the same thing.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTabler();
    });

    function refreshTabler(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('/includes/friend.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTabler, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any .htaccess rules that might be causing a problem?

Comment: What is the URL you use to access your script?

Comment: How about folders inside includes ... say `includes\js\`?

Comment: No no .htaccess rules have been set. The URL to it is http://chiveandroidtaylor.org.uk/includes/header.php/ It does the notifications in the corner, it would usually show numbers in the red bubbles but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript code is in the parent directory of the includes folder, try:

```
'./includes/friend.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel like a bit of a plum now after hours of trying to find the problem all it was was on the pages that it wasn't working I was missing `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.